# What's the format for date-time constants in the DevExpress expression language?

Tags: winforms, devexpress

I need to generate the expression for DevExpress' WinForms data grid conditional formatting at runtime, and I can't find documentation that would say what the valid format is for its date-time constants/literals. All the only relevant [documentation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/6214/Common-Features/Expressions/Expression-Operators-Functions-and-Constants) I could find says is:

> Date-time constants must be wrapped in '#'.
>
> `[OrderDate] >= #1/1/2009#`

The examples seem to imply this is MM/DD/YYYY format, but it's never spelled out outright; or whether the format used remains the same, or dependent on the current culture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you build parameterized criteria using the **positional parameters**. 
This approch allows you to avoid formatting errors:

```
// Possible formatting errors
var criteria = CriteriaOperator.Parse("[OrderDate] >= #1/1/2009#")

// Using positional parameter. No formatting errors.
var criteria = CriteriaOperator.Parse("[OrderDate] >= ?", new DateTime(2009, 1, 1))
```

Take a look at the [Criteria Language Syntax](https://documentation.devexpress.com/CoreLibraries/4928/DevExpress-Data-Library/Criteria-Language-Syntax) documentation article for details.